# hapi good register error is undefined both on sucess and error

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm wondering if there is something wrong with this code:

```
var options = {
    opsInterval: 1000,
        reporters: [
            {
                    reporter: require('good-console'),
                    events: { log: '*', response: '*' }
            },
            {
                    reporter: require('good-file'),
                    events: { ops: '*' },
                    config: './log/good.log'
            }
        ]
};

server.register(
    {
            register: require('good'),
            options: options
    },
    function (err) {console.log(err)
        if (err) {
                    return console.error(err);
            }
            server.start(function () {
            console.info('Server started at ' + server.info.uri);
                });

    }
);
```

if for instance I set like

```
config: './thereIsNotDirHere/good.log'
```

the err is always undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you put an err argument in server.start callback and throw error you should be able to see error returned.

```
server.start(function (err) {

     if (err) {
         throw err;
     }
     console.info('Server started at ' + server.info.uri);
});
```

Comment: Whisher - can I have some feedback on my answer?

Comment: Did this answer help you find error?  Can I have some feedback?